# Max date from multiple tables

Tags: date, max, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau. I have found several answers here  but I can't make them apply. It may be that I just don't know enough yet.
I just want the max date to show one time.
I have tried **{fixed: max([Date])}** but it keeps giving me the max date of the entire table, not by Project Title. I have also tried the solution from Tableau community called Max Group_AM and to no avail. Here is a screenshot of my real data and results.  I created a dummy sheet to see if someone could help. I've been working on this off and on (mostly on)for 3 weeks. It's for work and I'm stumped.[Format of tableau report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuUGy.png).

Cannot attach the workbook.
Here's Dummy Data

Name (Name Table    Task Status (Project Closeout Table)    Project Title (Project Table)   Project Sub Code (Project Table)    Note (Note Table)   Insert date( Note Table)
Cool, Dennis    Incomplete  Recreate Support Team   TAN-21622   Project opened  Jan. 11, 2014
Kartwright, Laura   Incomplete  Accounts Receivable TAN-64500   Project closed  Oct. 12, 2012
Cool, Dennis    Incomplete  Recreate Support Team   TAN-21622-4 Project reopened    April 1, 2015
Kartwright, Laura   Incomplete  Accounts Receivable TAN-64500   Project closed  Feb. 28, 2012
Cool, Dennis    Incomplete  Recreate Support Team   TAN-21622-2 Project closed  March 14, 2014
Kartwright, Laura   Incomplete  Accounts Receivable TAN-64500   Project cancelled   June 30, 2012
Cool, Dennis    Incomplete  Recreate Support Team   TAN-21622-3 Project closed  Sept. 10, 2015
Kartwright, Laura   Incomplete  Accounts Receivable TAN-64500-44    Project closed  April 30,2012
Kartwright, Laura   Incomplete  Accounts Receivable TAN-64500-6 Project reopened    June 12, 2012
Faas, Josh  Incomplete  Displaced Workers   ROH-19566   Project Opened  Jan. 3, 2015
Kartwright, Laura   Incomplete  Accounts Receivable TAN-64500-44    Project reopened    April 1, 2012
Faas, Josh  Incomplete  Displaced Workers   ROH-19566-1 Project closed  Jan. 3, 2016
Kartwright, Laura   Incomplete  Accounts Receivable TAN-64500-45    Project opened  Feb. 26, 2012

Comment: Please use proper coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using tableau desktop? Edit your calculated field to group by "Project Title".

```
{FIXED [Project Title]: MAX([Insert Date])}
```

For more information around Level of Detail(LOD) expressions have a look at the below link:

http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to reply. I starting using this yesterday and it worked wonderfully. I tried it last week but I didn't understand which dimension to use. I'm now going to try and use the LAST function to only get the date to display once.